# Add attribute to an object at index from array at same index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two arrays, one with objects containing multiple attributes:

```
var peopleArray = [{name: 'James', lastname: 'Stanley'}, {name: 'Roger', lastname 'Moore'}];
```

And one array with random words:

```
var wordArray = ['Banana', 'Sword'];
```

My goal is to add each word from **wordArray** as a new attribute to each object in **peopleArray** based on index.

E.g. the word "Banana" is at index 0 in wordArray so it will be added to the object at the same index in peopleArray, which is "James".

I hope it was clear, any guidance in any way appreciated! I really don't know how to achieve this

Comment: did u write any code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var index = 0; index < peopleArray.length; index++) {
    peopleArray[index][nameOfNewAttr] =wordArray[index]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really pretty simple:

```
const n = Math.min(peopleArray.length, wordArray.length);
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    peopleArray[i].word = wordArray[i];
}
```